system-wide script for remote graphical sessions in ubuntu 22.04 with xfce
I am using ubuntu 22.04 with xfce.
I want to put a script that does:
ln -fs /path/to/folder ~/

Everytime a user logs in via graphical remote access (particularly, I'm using remmina).
I tried /etc/profile.d, /etc/bash.bashrc, /etc/X11/Xsession.d, /etc/gdm3/PostLogin/Default.sample... nothing works. Maybe I need to restart some service?
I found this but this is user-specific. Same for this. Several other forum discussions led me nowhere.
Thanks in advance for any help to this hopeless soul.

Can you give us a few more details? Why would you need to do this multiple times on login? Can't you just do it once, and add it to the automatic steps performed when a new user is created?

@terdon thanks for the help. Initially yes, we can do it only once every user is created (would that be something below /etc/skel?). However, it is something that is going to scale to a large operation environment where everything can happen and chaos reigns. Doing it everytime there is a login would improve system reliability in my opinion.

Frankly, I doubt that. I mean, symlinks don't disappear, they only need to be created once, so re-doing this on every login seems odd and very unlikely to improve reliability. Far more likely to make things worse since there would now be multiple opportunities for failure. And yes, it could be done using skel files, or even by having your system create the symlinks on boot, or with a cron command. Trying to do this on graphical login is needlessly complex.

I partially agree with your point, we have indeed decided to put stuff in /etc/skel. Can you submit this as an answer so I can accept it? I just want to note two things: 1 - multiple possibilities for failure in this case is not a problem since bash is made for that: it fails non-catastrophically and keeps going and that is exactly what I want and what we have been doing for years. 2 - Although symlinks don't just disappear, I dont have enough characters to say the number of weird stuff I have seen users doing to their own homes once you scale your system up and operate for enough time.

The main issue here is that there are many ways that graphical login is managed and some of those might read /etc/profile, or /etc/profile.d files, or ~/.profile, but not all are guaranteed to. So I would try adding the command to the user's ~/.profile files, but that isn't guaranteed to work.
Instead, I would modify the user-creation process, using the /etc/skel system or configuring through /etc/adduser.conf, to ensure that the symlink is created when the user is.
Now, you very correctly mention that users do weird stuff, and that's a very valid concern. So even if you create the link on user creation, you also want to protect against your users doing something, um, creative, like deleting it. I can think of a few workarounds:

Move the link into a directory, and make that directory undeletable:
## create a directory with rwxr-xr-x permissions, owned by root
$ sudo mkdir /home/$username/links
$ sudo ln -sf  /path/to/folder /home/$username/links/

Now, your users cannot delete the symlink, but it is no longer directly under ~/.

Have a cron job run every minute that creates the symlink.
Make a script that goes through all homes and creates the symlink:
#!/bin/bash

for userhome in /home/*; do
  [[ -l "$userhome/folder" ]] || ln -s /path/to/folder "$userhome"
done

Or, if you also want to protect against your users uing the same symlink name to point somewhere else, just:
#!/bin/bash

for userhome in /home/*; do
  ln -sf /path/to/folder "$userhome"
done

Save that as fixlinks.sh and add this to /etc/crontab:
* *    * * *   root    /path/to/fixlinks.sh

This is ugly, and cumbersome, but it will at least ensure that nobody is left without the link for more than a minute or so.

Use a bind mount.
Forget symlinks, instead, bind mount the directory into another directory inside the user's $HOME. You would, again, need to do this as part of the user creation process for new users. The idea is something like this:
sudo mkdir /home/$username/links/
sudo mount --bind /path/to/folder /home/$username/links/

You could add a @reboot cron job that sets all this up, or use /etc/fstab for the mounting. Now, the user has a ~/links directory which is the /path/to/folder directory. They can use it, but they can't delete or unmount it:
$ mkdir link
$ sudo mount --bind /test/ link
$ rm -r link
rm: cannot remove 'link': Device or resource busy
$ umount link
umount: /home/terdon/link: must be superuser to unmount.



One of the workarounds might be a solution for you, depending on the details of what you're doing.
